# UIView.convert gives wrong result while calculating UITableViewCell subview in UIWindow

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

While I try to convert coordinates of a subview in UITableViewCell inside UIWindow, it gives result without adding UINavigationBar's height, as if it is situated on top of the screen, but it is situated inside UINavigationController. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
open var targetView: UIView? {
    didSet {
        if let tView = targetView {
            targetFrame = self.convert(self.frame, to: tView)
        }
    }
}
```

self is a subview inside UITableViewCell, targetView is UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a most simple application to test this out and it worked perfectly. You might be missing the call to the `superview` though it seems strange that would have the exact difference of the height of the navigation bar. Anyway try:

```
targetFrame = self.superView!.convert(self.frame, to: tView) // TODO: remove the force-unwrap
```

What I used was a table view in the navigation bar with delegate method:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let view = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    //  let view = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel // Also works
        let parent = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        let converted = view?.superview?.convert(view!.frame, to: parent)
        print("\(converted)")
    }
```

The printed values did include the navigation bar.

Comment: call to superView is 'a major key' :)

Comment: @dev View's frame is defined from its superview's perspective. View's bounds is from its internal though. So converting bounds instead of the frame may do the trick as well.